# I met a mistake : Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double

Tags: java

I am writing a program to compute payment.

The whole code is here :

```java
class DaisyDriveIn {
    double computePay(double hours){
        if (hours > 20) {
            return 8.00 * 20 + (hours - 20) * 10.00;
        } else {
            return hours * 7.00;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DaisyDriveIn m = new DaisyDriveIn();
        double pay;
        pay = m.computePay(23);
        System.out.printf("Your payment is : %d'\n'" , pay);
    }
}
```

But it failed and gave me warning that :
Your payment is : Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double

How to fix it? Thanking you for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is that you using the `%d` in `System.out.printf("Your payment is : %d'\n'" , pay);` the `%d` sign is used for integer's. Use `%f` for all floating point numbers instead.

`System.out.printf("Your payment is : %f'\n'" , pay);`